# Modify multiple a href targets with input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1) I want to add multiple input values, each with an "OK" button and its a tag.

2) When the "OK" button is pressed, it changes the href value of its a tag to the input tag value whose "OK" button was pressed.

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tzLac9zt/8/

(Code in fiddle)

1) Is done, problem is 2)

Tried this but did not work:

```
var number_button = $('button[name=boton1]');
var number_link = $('input[name=linknum1]');

document.querySelector('number_button').addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Store value
  var valor = $('number_link').text(value);

  // change href value
  $('a[name=descarga1]').attr('href', value);

});
```

Tried to do it first for a single case, then for everyone.

Calling them through their names so I can catch the specific value that I want to change, dont know if this is the proper way to do it though.

Comment: Check and see what `document.querySelector('number_button')` looks like. I'm pretty sure that if `number_button` is a class, it should be `.number_button`. Also, `document.querySelector` returns an array, regardless of how many matches you get. You have to loop over them and `addEventListener` to each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here, I simplified a bit you "cloning" code, using the `clone` method. I also added a class to the buttons so I can select all of them and bind a click listener to execute what you want to achieve.

The trick is simple here, clone the first controls, then empty the textfield and the href attribute of the cloned element children, then show them to the screen. Given the class of the button and the listener on that class, you will automatically have the behavior you want without writing a lot of code and this is due to the usage of `siblings` which returns the specified siblings of an element.

Here is a fiddle for demo :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#addrow").on('click', function() {
   var clone = $('.controls').first().clone(true);
        clone.find('a').attr('href', '');
        clone.find('input[type=text]').val('');
        clone.appendTo('.ytlink').hide().slideDown();
  })
  
  $('.goBtn').on('click', function() {
 var link = $(this).siblings('a');
        var input = $(this).siblings('input[type=text]');
   link.attr('href', input.val());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ytlink">
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <input class="span3" placeholder="Insert Link" type="text" name="linknum1">
    <button type="button" class = "goBtn" name="boton1">Ok</button>
    <a href="" name="descarga1"> go to this inputs href </a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <a href="#" id="addrow"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add </a>
```